# Hybrid Cordova App callback for location permission alert

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have a **cordova hybrid app** which using `location` permission. so is there anyway in `JavaScript` to detect the action performed on alert popup either `allow` or `cancel`.
something like in Android we have callback `onRequestPermissionsResult`.

[image]

i'm using `Geolocation API` for getting location `navigator.geolocation`

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position)=> {
    console.log(position);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by using [cordova-diagnostic-plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin) to request location permission:

Configure it:

`config.xml`: `<preference name="cordova.plugins.diagnostic.modules" value="LOCATION" />`

Install it:

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova.plugins.diagnostic
```

Use [`requestLocationAuthorization()`](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#requestlocationauthorization):

```
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.requestLocationAuthorization(function(status){
    switch(status){
        case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.NOT_REQUESTED:
            console.log("Permission not requested");
            break;
        case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.GRANTED:
            console.log("Permission granted");
            break;
        case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.DENIED:
            console.log("Permission denied");
            break;
        case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.DENIED_ALWAYS:
            console.log("Permission permanently denied");
            break;
    }
}, function(error){
    console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: sorry but don't want use this plugin any other method we have which will give call back like `navigator.permissions.query({name:'geolocation'})` .