# Is there any alternative to navigator.permissions.query Permissions API?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, google-maps-api-3, w3c-geolocation

Is there any alternative to `navigator.permissions.query` *[Permissions API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions/query)* query to check `geolocation` permission.
cause its still in Working Draft and has less Browser compatibility.

***W3C Permissions Ref :*** https://www.w3.org/TR/permissions/

Issue is `app resume` once user perform action on **native permission popup** then wanted to check the `action` being taken by user.

[Hybrid Cordova App callback for location permission alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52619405/hybrid-cordova-app-callback-for-location-permission-alert)

**Platform** : Mobile Android

**NOTE** : Don't want to use `cordova diagnostic plugin`

Example:

```
navigator.permissions.query({name:'geolocation'}).then(function(result) {

  console.log('result : ', result);

});
```

Comment: any particular `name`?

Comment: im checking for `geolocation` permission.

Comment: On what platform(s)?

Comment: Mobile Android.

Comment: Have you tried android permission plugin? https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/plugin.html#android-permissions

Comment: @QuickFix don't want to use any cordova plugin here.

Comment: @ShivKumarBaghel How about adding the permission to manifest xml using cordova custom config plugin so that you need not have to check for it? The plugin here is not to check permission but to set it.

Comment: sorry @Gandhi i need to ask user's permission before getting his location.

Comment: @ShivKumarBaghel If that's the case, you will not be able to check permissions without cordova plugins as it requires interaction with the device.

Comment: @Gandhi `navigator.permissions.query` is available solution to check the permissions. but its still in `working draft` and has less browser support, specially in mobile browsers. so looking for alternatives.

Answer (score 9):

You can directly use `navigator.geolocation` without asking permission first. it will automatically raise ask location prompt like the `navigator.permissions` do.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  (i)=>console.log('success',i),
  (i)=>console.log('failed',i)
)
```

`navigator.permissions` is not supported in safari and edge, but `navigator.geolocation` is supported, so i think it's safe to just execute geolocation without checking permission because it also will raise prompt permission first.

Comment: Wonder if there's a way to know if the user has allowed access before. I don't just want to flat out ask them for it before explaining why I'm going to request it. In some cases, the user's instinct would be to just decline it.

Comment: navigator.permissions is now supported in edge
https://caniuse.com/?search=navigator.permissions

Comment: Any alternative for safari ?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so.

At this moment the navigator.permissions object is undefined - probably it's removed in WebView by purpose to not mix web permissions with android permissions.

**Option 1:**

You may try [Cordova diagnostic plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin), specifically the `getLocationAuthorizationStatus` method which should return permission state in very similar way to Permissions API.
Please note I haven't tried the plugin.

**Option 2:**

Trigger location permissions dialog by requesting location.
When you'll receive [PositionError](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PositionError) with `PERMISSION_DENIED` constant code, it'll mean that user denied location permission (just now or at app settings).

```
navigator.getCurrentPosition(
  function(position) { /** won't be executed for such short timeout */ },
  function(positionError) {
    switch (positionError.code) {
    // PERMISSION_DENIED
    case 1:
      console.log('Permission denied')
      break
    // POSITION_UNAVAILABLE
    case 2:
      console.log('Permission allowed, location disabled')
      break
    // TIMEOUT
    case 3:
      console.log('Permission allowed, timeout reached')
      break
    }
  },
  {timeout: 0}
)
```

Comment: thanks @piotr_cz  for reply. but issue is i cant use the `diagnostic plugin` thats why i was looking for other solution. by your solution if im running `navigator.getCurrentPosition` then the permission native dialog is coming by which the app is going into `background` from `foreground` after `resume` to app i want to check that what user action performed on the dialog.

Comment: You have to come with some workaround, because as I noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52662150/navigator-permissions-query-not-working-in-android-ios-webview/52807516#52807516) Permissions API is probably removed by design.

Comment: according to **W3C**  https://www.w3.org/TR/permissions/  its still in `Working Draft` so some Browsers has support some don't.

Comment: Well, _Chrome Mobile_ 69.0.3497.100 has Permissions API, but _Android System WebView_ with the same version doesn't.

Comment: yes true.i have hybrid app that will serve to different android `WebView`. so want a solution without using any `cordova` plugin like `Cordova diagnostic plugin` something.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you using two WebViews in one app?

Comment: no only one `webview` i have ... i only want to test if permission granted or not ....without calling `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`. leave the `webview` is it possible check in `JavaScript` if we **allow** or **denied** the **permission**