# Angular: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.permission.query')

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, geolocation

I am using the MEAN stack and use google maps. I want to get the geolocation of the user if permission is granted. For that I use this code snippet here:

```
getCurrentLocation() {
      navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'geolocation' }).then((status) => {
         if (status.state === 'granted' || status.state === 'prompt') {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
               this.center = {
                  lat: position.coords.latitude,
                  lng: position.coords.longitude,
               };
               this.lat = position.coords.latitude;
               this.lng = position.coords.longitude;
               this.getNearByPois(this.center.lat, this.center.lng);
            });
         } else {
            this.getNearByPois(this.center.lat, this.center.lng);
         }
      });
   }`
```

It works fine on my Windows PC and on my Android phone but I have a problem with my Apple devices (iPhone and Mac).

I always get the error `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.permission.query')`

I am confused why it doesn't work on Apple devices?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/permissions#browser_compatibility

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52784495/is-there-any-alternative-to-navigator-permissions-query-permissions-api

Comment: Thanks. I added `if ( navigator.permissions && navigator.permissions.query )` before and it seems to work now